# jQuery .hover() or .animate() causing bubbled animations in Marquee plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, marquee

I'm playing with [Giva Labs jQuery Marquee plugin](http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm). Example [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AkQgH/).

There are two toggling lines of text in the example: `First line` and `Second row`. When you start to continuously move mouse cursor over and out the light-blue box, the text goes crazy: the lines start to move over each other like randomly, out of order. The craziness is strongest when you change speed of mouse movements from slow to fast in a loop.

I googled for "jquery animate stop" and found the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) effects. I tried attaching these to the marquee effect like this:

```
$("#marquee").marquee().stop();
```

and this:

```
$("#marquee").marquee().clearQueue();
```

and also like this:

```
$("#marquee").marquee()
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).clearQueue();
    });
```

I also tried with the plugin's build-in [methods](http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm#methods):

```
$("#marquee").marquee()
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).marquee("pause");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).marquee("resume");
    });
```

None of them worked.

How to get rid of this glitch?

Comment: Which browser are the problems showing up in?  I added the last bit of code you posted to your jsfiddle and tried rapid mouse movement and the text stopped / paused as expected.  I am using Chrome.

Comment: @Lokase Chrome. Also checked in IE8 and Firefox - replicated in both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE/SOLVED**:

**Code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YtdAS/1/)**

---

**Solution summary:**

- added `var timedout`
- set `timedout` inside `scroll()`
- call `clearTimeout(timedout)` inside `pause()`

---

The bug doesn't occur when you put a very low `pauseSpeed` (like 2 for example), which leads me to believe the bug it happens because of the interaction between `pause()` and `resume()`

Concretely, this bit of code in `pause()`:

```
if( $marquee.data("marquee.showing") != true ){
    // we must dequeue() the animation to ensure that it does indeed stop animation
    $lis.filter("." + options.cssShowing).dequeue().stop();
}
```

this bit of code in `resume()`:

```
if ($marquee.data("marquee.showing") != true) scroll($lis.filter("." + options.cssShowing), 1);
```

and this bit of code in `scroll()`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // if paused, stop processing (we need to check to see if the pause state has changed)
    if (paused == true) return false;

    // scroll the message down
    $li.animate({
        top: (options.yScroll == "top" ? "+" : "-") + $marquee.innerHeight() + "px"
    }, options.showSpeed, options.fxEasingScroll);
    // finish showing this message
    finish($li);
}, delay);​
```

As far as I can see the problem occurs because `dequeue().stop()` [which makes sense] is immediate and and `scroll(...)` has some code that happens with a delay (`pauseSpeed)`.

So what happens is the following:

1. the animation is cancelled in `pause()`
2. then `resume()` calls `scroll()` which in turns sets a timeout function to occur in 2000 ms
3. actually it creates one for every time you hover over and move out
4. which is what ends up messing everything up... don't ask me how, I'm pretty tired now

To fix this I would suggest editing `jquery.marquee.js` code and actually calling `clearTimeout()` every time you stop the animation.

Comment: actually I think I even know how this happens, but my brain is too fried to explain now. Hint: it will be possible to reproduce this bug every time pausespeed is greater than showspeed. The solution I proposed should work.

Comment: haha, it happens anyway, but it has to be because of all the timed out functions that get put in the queue. They did a good job of making sure to stop the animation, but not the timed out events. If you search ***clearTimeout*** in their code, there isn't any.

Comment: here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YtdAS/    It works now. I've just added the timedout, set it in scroll(), and then call clearTimeout(timedout) in pause()

Comment: Most excellent bug fix. :-D Thanks for tracking it down. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your code into JSFiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/AkQgH/7/

I am not able to replicate fast movement. The reason you are getting fast scroll is as you move out and in your cursor within specific block it it generate pause and play event.
You can use

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
  }, 5000);
```

after pause event to delay for number of time you want to wait and it will not create strange effect.

Updated URL. Removed JS errors so far as in your code should be "marquee" not "marque". 
-- also other error is instead "over" you need to use "mouseover"

Comment: Thanks, but none of those worked. The fiddle is very similar to one of the solutions I already tried (you binded to `mouseover`, I did to `hover`). `setTimeout` does not seem to fix it. I found out that the glitch is strongest when I change speed of mouse movements from slow to fast.